# Is there a way to easily convert a unordered_map<K, shared_ptr<T>> to unordered_map<K, shared_ptr<const T>>?

Tags: c++, constants, shared-ptr, unordered-map

As the title suggests, I would like to know if there is a way to convert a `std::unordered_map<K, std::shared_ptr<T>>` to a `std::unordered_map<K, std::shared_ptr<const T>>` that would allow me to do something like this:

```
class KeyClass;
class ValueClass;

void f(const std::unordered_map<KeyClass, std::shared_ptr<const ValueClass>>& map)
{
    // do whatever but make sure that absolutely nothing changes
}

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<KeyClass, std::shared_ptr<ValueClass>> map;
    // init the map
    f(map);
}
```

The reason I am asking is that I made sure that at least the conversion from `std::shared_ptr<T>` can be implicitly converted to `std::shared_ptr<const T>`.

What I am conceptually aiming at is to make sure that nothing in the `map` argument and itself will be changed. Is this overkill in any way ?

Comment: You can *copy* the elements of the first map into a (temporary) map of the second kind.

Comment: You can't easily do this. You could wrap your map in a class with a const-correct interface to maintain the invariance. Edit : There might be something in [range](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) though I'm not familiar enough with it to say.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux [`std::experimental::propagate_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const) would work as a wrapper for this situation